# Simple Web-To-Lead but with additional email verification (Double-Opt-In)

Tags: email, web2lead, gdpr

On our website (Wordpress-backed) we currently use the standard Web-To-Lead form from Salesforce.

As we get a lot of spam from it AND to comply with the new European Privacy law GDPR we want to add an email verification step (Double-Opt-In).

Is there something (preferred free) out there to do that? I guess Salesforce must have provided something as part of GDPR.